# HTML <iframe> issue

Tags: html, iframe

Currently my situation is that I would like to display a few videos in a web page using **iframe**. However it is only displaying 1 video instead of 10. I'm not sure what is going wrong here but when I put the same link of the 1st **iframe src="..."** into **2nd iframe src="..."** the video will show up. Fyi, I also try using **object** and **embed** but both of these don't seem to work. Is this a problem with youtube or something? Below is my code. Here's my code. Thanks. :)

```
<div class="box text-shadow">
                 <table class="demo-tbl"><!--<item>1</item>-->
                 <tr class="tbl-item"><!--<img/>-->
                 <td class=""><iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nn2eWc4PxhM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                                                    </iframe></td>
                 <!--<data></data>-->
                 <td class="td-block"><p class="date">03/15/2012</p>

                 <p class="title">Arch</p>

                 <p class="desc">An arch is a structure that spans a space and
                                                    supports a load. Arches appeared as early as the 2nd millennium
                                                    BC in Mesopotamian brick architecture and their systematic use
                                                    started with the Ancient Romans who were the first to apply the
                                                    technique to a wide range of structures.</p>

                 <p class="like">5 Likes</p></td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--<item>2</item>-->
                 <tr class="tbl-item"><!--<img/>-->
                 <td class=""><iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ijxB1NBvLEc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td>
                 <!--<data></data>-->
                 <td class="td-block"><p class="date">03/18/2012</p>

                 <p class="title">Architecture</p>

                 <p class="desc">Architecture is both the process and product of
                                                    planning, designing and construction. Architectural works, in
                                                    the material form of buildings, are often perceived as cultural
                                                    symbols and as works of art. Historical civilizations are often
                                                    identified with their surviving architectural achievements.</p>

                 <p class="like">25 Likes</p></td>
                 </tr>
                 <!--<item>3</item>-->
                 <tr class="tbl-item"><!--<img/>-->
                 <td class=""><iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-8T7707U4w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                 </iframe></td>
                 <!--<data></data>-->
                 <td class="td-block"><p class="date">01/16/2011</p>

                 <p class="title">Autumn</p>

                 <p class="desc">Autumn or Fall is one of the four temperate seasons.
                                                    Autumn marks the transition from summer into winter, in
                                                    September (Northern Hemisphere) or March (Southern Hemisphere)
                                                    when the arrival of night becomes noticeably earlier. The
                                                    equinoxes might be expected to be in the middle of their
                                                    respective seasons, but temperature lag (caused by the thermal
                                                    latency of the ground and sea) means that seasons appear later
                                                    than dates calculated from a purely astronomical
                                                    perspective.</p>

                 <p class="like">12 Likes</p></td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in your first closing `</iframe>` tag, check your code, you wrote `</iframe`, without the "`>`". Second, notice how you used the "embed" link in your first iframe but the "watch" link in the second and third? Change it with embed and you're good to go. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qrqL8tj2/1/

Example link:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/Nn2eWc4PxhM
```

Comment: Sorry, it appears that Im a typo when I'll try to edit the code in here. I've already edit the question.

Comment: Of course it does, check the jsfiddle link, I can clearly see three videos - http://jsfiddle.net/qrqL8tj2/1/

Comment: Good God **embed**. Thanks sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your src in . The source you given is incorrect. your src should be in the format of > https://www.youtube.com/embed/PQgWnRe9trwcopy the link you need from **youtube Embed option**.

Comment: Isn't this the same answer as mine?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. That **embed** thing is missing, and it works now. Cheers! :)

Comment: the solution I got I wrote that one.